# Disabled ListItem is enabled when displayed in a JQuery UI Dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-dialog

I have an UserControl and in it, a DropDownList. I'm using this code to add a disabled separator to the list of items:

```
ListItem separador1 = new ListItem(" -- -- -- -- -- ", "Separador");
separador1.Attributes.Add("disabled", "true");
this.ddlPais.Items.Add(separador1);
```

It works OK when the user control is displayed in a Page normally, but when it is located in a JQuery UI Dialog the separators items don't have the enabled attribute and off course they are enabled.

**Important Note**: I managed to solve my problem while still typing the question in. I will post it anyway in case someone experience what I think is a jquery bug.

The solution was to add the disabled attribute after opening the JQuery Dialog.

```
$("#" + PanelClientId).dialog( "open" );
$("#" + PanelClientId).parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));    
$('option[value="Separador"]').attr('disabled','true'); //This is new in my code
```

Comment: Could you post the solution in the answers area below and accept it? Otherwise people tend to see this as unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it with a workaround. The solution was to add the disabled attribute in each pageLoad; it has to be the client side pageLoad to disable items after each async postback since I'm using UpdatePanel.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad(sender, args) { 
        $('option[value="Separador"]').attr('disabled','true');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve this in the code, just use:

```
separador.Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
```

I think the problem is when the code is added to the DOM via jQuery, the attribute is not recognized as valid.

Comment: I tried your solution but the result is the same: the item is enabled when rendered in a JQuery Dialog.